# Reinstall ROM from a new SD from scratch

Tags: rom-flashing, sd-card, miui

My HTC Desire (Bravo) rebooted by itself in the middle of the night; the result is that I lost all the apps that were installed on the SD card (that is probably corrupted). Now that I have another SD card, i’d like to reinstall the ROM that was on the phone (Rooted - MIUI 2.35a) from scratch and from the new SD.

I installed a new recovery, but when I switch the SD cards, the classic recovery starts and I’m not allowed to install anything. I tried with and without partitioning the SD but nothing. If I let the phone start with the new SD nothing happens and all I get is a twenty-minutes HTC splash screen.

How do I manage to reinstall everything with a brand new SD without touching the old one? I did all the backups, so I can fully wipe all without problems, it’s just that I don’t want to reinstall the ROM on a corrupted SD and make the copy afterwards.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the old SDCard still readable using a card reader attached to your computer? Then you could copy everything over to the new SDCard that way. I'm not sure why your recovery "disappears" just when switching to an empty card (as it is usually installed on the device), but this should at least solve a part of your problem.

Comment: You can install the ROM from the old sdcard! .zip includes integrity checks via checksums for each file. PS: it's not a given that your sdcard is faulty, it could very well also be the main data partition (it holds the encryption keys and other meta information for the (securely) stored apps on the sdcard

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it by myself. I partitioned the SD (with gparted live) in full FAT32, then I loaded the Clockwork Recovery on it and it ran perfectly.

Then I successfully wiped the phone, partitioned the SD and installed the ROM.

Now my phone has a new Android installation with a brand new SD.